# Spotlight menu item on OS X 10.9 sometimes does not function (beeps instead)

Tags: macos, spotlight

I'm running into a situation now and then when the Spotlight menu on OS X 10.9 can't be activated. When I click on its magnifying glass icon I receive only an error indication (beep tone) but get no chance to enter any search terms.

This can happen even if no programs have been launched and while the other menu items work as expected.

What causes this behavior and can it be overcome? (I have by now become reliant on Spotlight to open all kinds of documents, etc., so this seeming misbehavior is esp. unfortunate.)

Comment: the answer below doesn't work for me. I suspect Alfred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same thing was happening to me. Tried the keyboard shortcut (cmd+space, or option+cmd+space) and it worked and now seems to work fine even when I click.

Comment: This worked for me too. I first had to enable the keyboard shortcut via system preferences. However it seems that it is indexing exceptionally slowly, as if for the first time.

Comment: Worked for me too. My spotlight stopped working after flipping back from VMWare.

Comment: Damn, doesn't work for me. Beeps if I click the icon or use the shortcut.